# When redirect_uri may be omitted in oauth authorization request?

Tags: oauth-2.0, specifications

I read [The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) and can not understand, when `redirect_uri` may be omitted in `oauth authorization`.

[3.1.2.3.  Dynamic Configuration](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1.2.3) says: If multiple redirection URIs have been registered, if only part of
the redirection URI has been registered, or if no redirection URI has
been registered, the client MUST include a redirection URI with the
authorization request using the "redirect_uri" request parameter.

So, "redirect_uri" request parameter MUST be included always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there's one and only one `redirect_uri` registered for the Client, it may be omitted from the Authorization Request since the Provider would know unambiguously where to send the Authorization Response.

Comment: where is it indicated in the specifications? i can't find it.

Comment: it is not explicit but it logically follows from the very sentence that you've pasted since it is the only case left

Comment: Oh, thanks! I read this sentence many times and can't find last case.

Answer (score 0):

"OpenID Connect Core 1.0, [3.1.2.1. Authentication Request](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest)" says `redirect_uri` is *REQUIRED*. So, my understanding is that `redirect_uri` parameter is always required when an authorization request should be regarded as an *OpenID Connect request*.

A certain implementation always requires `redirect_uri` parameter (even if the number of registered redirect URIs is 1) when a request contains `openid` in `scope` parameter. The reason the implementation judges whether a request is an OpenID Connect request or a normal RFC 6749 request based on whether `openid` is included in `scope` parameter or not is that "[3.1.2.1. Authentication Request](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest)" says as follows.

```
scope
    REQUIRED. OpenID Connect requests MUST contain the openid scope value.
    If the openid scope value is not present, the behavior is entirely
    unspecified. Other scope values MAY be present. Scope values used
    that are not understood by an implementation SHOULD be ignored. See
    Sections 5.4 and 11 for additional scope values defined by this
    specification.
```

Comment: Agreed but the question is about OAuth 2.0 instead of OpenID Connect; the latter extends OAuth 2.0 with indeed more strict and specific requirements such as the one you mention.